# Failed to load firebase (redirected error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to learn ajax and I don't know back end language yet so I'm using firebase from google and I am running my code through localhost:8000 using python 2.7. I'm trying to GET/POST to this server:

https://ajax-practice-1f1b9.firebaseio.com/

If you can't access it, my JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Will",
        "drink": "American with creme"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Donat",
        "drink": "Vanilla Macchiato"
    }
]
```

here's my HTML and javascript

```js
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://ajax-practice-1f1b9.firebaseio.com',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AJAX jQuery course</title>
        <!-- latest bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>JQuery Ajax Tutorial</h1>
        <h2>Coffee Order</h2>

        <ulid="orders"></ul>

        <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
        <p>drink: <input type="text" id="drink"></p>
        <button id="add-order">Add</button>

        <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase.js"></script> -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error on the console:

Failed to load https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ajax-practice-1f1b9/database/data/: Redirect from 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ajax-practice-1f1b9/database/data/' to 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ajax-practice-1f1b9/database/data/&followup=https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ajax-practice-1f1b9/database/data/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I did something similar using axios and ReactJs a while back and it worked without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `https://ajax-practice-1f1b9.firebaseio.com` will try to load the database in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). You are probably trying to get the data through Firebase's REST API, which requires that the URL ends in `.json`.

So to get the JSON for that location, use `https://ajax-practice-1f1b9.firebaseio.com/.json`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !! Thank you so much!