# JavaScript + firebase. How can I implement the request using fetch for farebase, so to delete item in farebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, fetch

```
API_BASE = `https://dims.firebaseio.com/`;
editResource = async (url, body) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${this.API_BASE}${url}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
    return await res.json();
}
editMember = async (memberId, body) => {
    return await this.editResource(`/UserProfile/${memberId}`, body);
}
delResource = async (url) => {
    await fetch(`${this.API_BASE}${url}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(response => response.json());
};
delMember = async (memberId) => {
    return await this.delResource(`/UserProfile/${memberId}`);
};
```

**result:**
OPTIONS: 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Access to fetch at 'https://dims.firebaseio.com//UserProfile/-M0r1o70-G2JMzQYXbm1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: You're missing the `.json` at the end of the URL, which is required when accessing Firebase Realtime Database through its REST API. Without a trailing `.json`, you're accessing the Firebase console, which returns the CORS error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795313/failed-to-load-firebase-redirected-error (which I found by [searching for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+has+been+blocked+by+CORS+policy)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's work.